# Android Google Cloud Print how to set document margins

Tags: android, printing, cloud, margins

I am developing an app that prints an image through Google Cloud Print.
It's working but I need to set the document margins.
How do I do that?

```
    String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.jpg";
    final File file = new File(fileName);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Intent printIntent = new Intent(this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
    printIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
    printIntent.putExtra("title", "image print");
    startActivity(printIntent);
```